# Do other languages have correspondences like English's No-Nope and Yeah-Yep?

Tags: english, phonology, phonetics, vocabulary, interjections

In the English language, as in others, there are a variety of interjection words. Among these are some comprising an open syllable, like yeah and no. Others end in stop consonants, like yep (or yup) and nope. In conversational speech, these words often seem to be realized with no audible release on the /p/ -  something like [p̚ʔ].

I think the correspondence of no and nope is clear; nope carries the same onset, nucleus, and definition as no yet adds an extra phoneme at the end. This is only slightly less clear with yep and yeah/yes, and I think they are part of the same phenomenon.

The creation of the words with the additional unreleased bilabial stop can easily be interpreted as speakers instinctively closing their mouth at the end of a short utterance, which produces an automatic [p̚]. Is this analysis correct?

Does something like this happen in other languages; if so, is it common? I am especially interested if it occurs in any languages and dialects that otherwise don't usually have unreleased word-final plosives or phonemic /p/.

Comment: "In conversational speech, these words often seem to be realized with no audible release on the /p/ - something like [p̚ʔ]" If there is no audible release, there is no yep and yup.

Comment: They emphasize the Y/N by closing the lips to mime completeness. It's essentially a phatic gesture, not a suffix or morpheme.

Comment: _Similar_ things definitely happen in other languages. Just within Germanic, we have for example Swedish _ja/nej_ (neutral) and _japp/nepp_ (informal), which are almost identical in formation to their English counterparts (and also frequently have unreleased [p̚] at the end); or Danish _jeps/niks_ (informal), which are similar, but add an additional _-s_ at the end (and has a velar instead of a labial in the negative).

Comment: @Lambie Are you suggesting that stops with no audible release are entirely imperceptible? Thus, go and goat are actually homophones? I don't know where you're from, but here in Chicago it would sound pretty odd if you DID release the /t/ at the end of goat.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean with "something like this"?

Comment: @Sverre I am looking for languages that have interjections or discourse markers ending with a closing-of-the-lips gesture, especially ones that correspond to another word without that gesture.

Comment: English also has "Wellp," especially to introduce a definitive comment.

Comment: Ukrainian has *tak* ~ *ta* for *yes* and *nê* [nʲi] ~ *nêt* [nʲit] for *no* where the first variation is standard, the second are dialectic or for memes. I dunno, is it what you want.

Comment: "Are you suggesting that stops with no audible release are entirely imperceptible?" No, I am saying that if you don't not pronounce ("release")  the p in yep, you don't get the word yep. You get "yeah", sound-wise.

Comment: @Lambie But that isn't true. Pronouncing and releasing a plosive are not the same thing.  By your logic, go and goat would be homophones in my accent. Maybe this post from Dr. John Wells will help clear your misunderstanding: http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-audible-release.html

Comment: @GrahamH. I don't care what you call it: the only difference between yep and yeah is the p sound. Without the p, you are not saying yep. Without the p, you cannot say the word. Even when you say yep, there is a pa at the end. You have to release the p or you can't pronounce it in final position.

Comment: @Lambie This disagreement is getting nowhere. You don't seem to be aware that a plosive with no audible release is not the same as no sound at all. [p] ≠ [p˺] ≠ [Ø]. You also try to substantiate your misunderstanding by falsely claiming that the only difference between "yeah" and "yep" is the /p/. This is false since the vowel in "yeah" is more open and likely longer and more front than the one in "yep."

Comment: @GrahamH. I simply do not understand how you can claim that "In conversational speech, these words often seem to be realized with no audible release on the /p/ - something like [p̚ʔ]." It has to be audible to be the word. Otherwise, without the /p/ it is NOT yep.

Comment: @Lambie The part that is audible is the sudden stoppage of air by the closing of the lips. The glottal stop which I think often occurs in "yep" and "nope" but not "yeah" and "no" might be as important or more important than the /p/. [jε] does not sound like [jεp˺ʔ] because the air isn't suddenly cut off at the lips and the glottis. There is also a possible pronunciation of "yet" as [jεt˺ʔ].

Answer (score 2):

French has “ouaip” (vs. neutral-register “oui”) for “yes”. I don’t know how often it is used. My impression is that French word final consonants are released more often than English ones.

Comment: Also, even *oui* / *ouais* exemplifies the closed/open distinction that probably is the key distinction here.

Answer (score 2):

In Classical Arabic the word for “no” is /lā/, but in many contemporary dialects it is pronounced /la’/, with a final glottal stop.

Answer (score 2):

In Hindi, *no* is *nahin* (nəɦiː), while *nope* is *na* (nʌ). 'Na' is sort of used with a similar cadence with which one would say 'yup' in English- I would go so far as to say that it's 'yup' minus the *p* and converting the *y* to an *n*. I hear it quite a lot in informal speech.